# How to cast and mold melt plastic to a shape and design you want?

Tags: casting

I am trying to use plastic for a cheap and easy casting but I'm having trouble in molding it to any given shape. I'm trying to see if I can make a spark plug and want to cast out a model for measuring and getting a feel for the design. But I never worked with plastic. I'm using HDPE plastic.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the trouble you're having? Describe your current process, what the end result looks like and how it doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Sounds like you'll want injection moulding

Comment: Any reason you don't just get yourself a RepRap and print a few?

Comment: For general information and tips, one could search YouTube for DIY casting. There are great videos for steel/iron casting, and I'm sure there must be several for plastics.

Answer (score 1):

I used to make candles in the wet sand by drawing out what I wanted it to look like. I guess it would work with plastic and then grind the sand out of it.

[image]